# ¿como exportar dato de un archivo.txt con selenium en c#?

Tags: c#

Buenos Tardes me lee lo que hay en el bloc de notas una lista de ciudades
using (StreamReader ReaderObject = new StreamReader(FileToRead))
Cuando ejecuto me sale chrome busca las ciudades pero se queda en una sola pagina y sale error en todas no aparece opcion de escoger alguna busqueda

```
        while ((Line = ReaderObject.ReadLine()) != null)
        
            driver.Url = "https://www.google.com.co/";
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys(Line);
            driver.ExecuteJavaScript("window.open('FileToRead', 'new tab')");
```

Comment: Podra ser quizas porque el archivo no existe en esa carpeta? lo validaste. Ademas no veo que tiene que ver selenium cuando es un codigo generico que lee un archivo

Comment: Lo que esta en la carpeta lo tengo que buscar en webdriver

Comment: No entiendo, tienes que buscar el contenido del archivo en buscador google? si es asi porque pones esa logica en el catch ? eso no seria correcto, se supone que la lectura del archivo debe ser correcta, por eso mencione que debes asegurar que el archivo esta en esa carpeta, podrias intentar ponerlo en una diferente. No se programa en catch ante un error

Comment: Sii hay una lista de palabras, ya me da pero esta sentencia no me busca sale error driver.ExecuteJavaScript("window.open('FileToRead', 'new tab')");

Comment: Pero entonces cambio el problema, cierra o edita esta pregunta explicando que es lo que sucede, si hay un mensaje de error deberias mencionarlo, solo decir "sale error" no aporta para entender que esta sucediendo